# Android - how to detect soft keyboard shown in the screen

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: how can i tell if the soft keyboard is showing or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568919/android-how-can-i-tell-if-the-soft-keyboard-is-showing-or-not)

how to detect whether the soft keyboard is shown in the screen or not in android?

Comment: have you referred this: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d318901586313204?pli=1

Comment: yes I have seen but that was posted on May 2009. Still we didnt find any approach to find this?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3568919/403455

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct way - see http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/1728f26f2334c060/5e4910f0d9eb898a where Dianne Hackborn from the Android team has replied. However, you can detect it indirectly by checking if the window size changed in #onMeasure. See [How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/android-is-software-keyboard-shown).