# Is it possible to determine soft keyboard size?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Is it possible to determine soft keyboard size in Android ?

Comment: thats the width of the screen right ?

Comment: okay.. i dont think so.. bcos it depends on which keyboard is being used.. wondering why u req it

Comment: Worst comment ever "Wondering why u req it"... :) I ALSO req it, because I'd like to have the biggest UI possible above the keyboard, when the keyboard is open.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25895869/2703209) shows a way to listen for size changes to your layout. Showing the keyboard will decrease the height, and the difference between old and new height is the height of the keyboard.