# How to close Android Soft KeyBoard programmatically?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am currently showing softkeyboard using the following code

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.RESULT_HIDDEN);
```

And Here I d'not bind the softkeyboard with Edittext because of that I had used the above code.

Now I want to close the SoftKeyboard so i am currently using the below code but it is not working.

```
imm.toggleSoftInput (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.RESULT_HIDDEN);
```

Can Anyone suggest me what to use for closing the softKeyboard ?

---

Based on Below Answer I want to let you clear that I am not using EditText, I use Layout on which I want to show Keyboard and Hide keyboard. I want to send keyboard key event to remote area bcoz of that I didnot used editText.

Comment: You code for hiding keyboard is same as code for showing the keyboard.

Comment: yes but i donot know what to use in place of that one..

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard) thread.

Comment: this doesn't working for me..plz read above edits

Comment: /* To Hide Soft Keyboard IN ONE LINE */
      `((InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),0);`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I have tested and this is working:

```
...
//to show soft keyboard
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);

//to hide it, call the method again
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

By the way, the second parameter of your code is not right, please have a look at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodSession.html#toggleSoftInput%28int,%20int%29).

Comment: Why do you use same code line for showing and hiding?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3568919/3990767 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4745988/3990767, it is quite difficult to check if the keyboard is shown, so toggling might not be a good idea if you don't know if it is already shown.

Comment: The problem with this approach is, if the user has hidden the keyboard, the second call will show up the keyboard again

Answer (score 41):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(EditTextName.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: @Mak Then use: getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken()

Answer (score 34):

Use this working code :

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: it works, thanks. I want to hide the keyboard when user click Login button, in this case, this solution works better than `imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0)`. because in landscape phone, the keyboard cover the Login button, and user have to hide the keyboard manually.

Answer (score 9):

**If you want, you can use entire class and call KeyboardUtil.hideKeyBoard(context) method wherever:**

```
public class KeyboardUtil
{
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity)
    {
        try
        {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
         }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Ignore exceptions if any
                Log.e("KeyBoardUtil", e.toString(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A solution that always works and sends flag "HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS", funny :)

Comment: This works well.  
There is no need of catching Exception though - catching Exception looks ugly.

Answer (score 5):

### Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

it's working for me i hope it's work for you..
```

### Open the Android Soft Keyboard

```
 InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (inputMethodManager != null) {
            inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

user942821's answer for hiding it works:

```
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

But this also works for me to hide it:

```
imm.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
```

You might also want to try:

```
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
```

When using '0' in the first parameter sometimes the keyboard toggles on in the wrong places under weird circumstances that I haven't been able to figure out how to duplicate yet. I'm still testing this last example, but will update when I find out more.

See [toggleSoftInput documentation page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodSession.html#toggleSoftInput%28int,%20int%29) for more information.

Comment: Well, `InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED` is just an enum which represent an int value. So of course it works, but that would be the same as if you set it to `InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN` which holds the value 0. Enum should be always used where it needs to be. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN

Comment: Sure, I understand, but shouldn't that go in the 2nd parameter? The first parameter is for showFlags.

`public void toggleSoftInput (int showFlags, int hideFlags) `

I think this is more appropriate:

`imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.RESULT_SHOWN, InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);`

Comment: Good point! :) Actually, there is no Enum Flag which supports the 0 value in the ShowFlags parameter. By reading the doc again I realized that they specify it can be 0. Sorry, my bad, although I don't find it a good practice not having provided a default Enum flag.

Comment: I've been looking into it as well, seems like you're supposed to use magic numbers here. I added a link to the docs.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine

```
InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getAttributes().token, 0);
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice.

Comment: Doesn't work in all cases. I'm finding out that this is a bigger problem then it first seems to capture all the edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is s solution, which checks if keyboard is visible

```
    public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        if (isKeyboardVisible(activity)) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isKeyboardVisible(Activity activity) {
        ///This method is based on the one described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device
        Rect r = new Rect();
        View contentView = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        contentView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
        int screenHeight = contentView.getRootView().getHeight();

        int keypadHeight = screenHeight - r.bottom;

        return
                (keypadHeight > screenHeight * 0.15);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager im =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
im.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

For hiding keyboard,

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Here, “mView” can be any view which is visible on screen

Answer (score 0):

This code hides the keyboard from inside `onItemClick` of an  `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterViewIn, View viewIn, int indexSelected, long arg3) {
     // whatever your code does
     InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(viewIn.getContext().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
     imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(viewIn.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Kotlin Extension to hide keyboard

```
// Simple, reuseable call anywhere in code
myView.hideKeyboard()

fun View.hideKeyboard() {
    val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

#### How to ***show*** soft keyboard

```
fun View.showKeyboard() {
    val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(SHOW_FORCED, HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY)
}
```

### Related further topics:

Simplify adding `Done`/`Next`... action to edittext: [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59758327/974045)

Remove requirement for ever using `getSystemService`: [Splitties Library](https://github.com/LouisCAD/Splitties/tree/master/modules/systemservices)

Answer (score 0):

```
  public void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(activity);
    }
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.RESULT_HIDDEN, 0);
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

and Call where you want

```
 hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide the keyboard programmatically::

```
fun hideKeypad() {
    val view = currentFocus
    if (view != null) {
        val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin way Hide and Show the Android Soft Keyboard:**

Create a Extension file in kotlin and add below code for hide/show the Keyboard.

```
> fun EditText.showKeyboard(){
  requestFocus()
  val insetsController = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(this)
  insetsController?.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
}

fun Activity.hideKeyboard(){
  val insetsController = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(window.decorView)
  insetsController?.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime())
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
private void close() {
    this.requestHideSelf(0);
}
```

this method is very simple

Comment: Uhh, where are you getting this method from?