# [Android]Handler setOnClickListener event in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialog

I have a quick question about setOnClickListener  event in EditText. I have an EditText that show a dialog when it is touched. But when I debug, my application does not show dialog in the first touching, it just show in the second touching. I think the problem is I using TextInputLayout for Edittext,but when i try some solution, these are not working. So How can I show my dialog in the first touching ?.

Here is my xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="60dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_departure"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:id="@+id/actv_departure"
                android:hint="Departure"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/actv_arrival"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_arrival"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:completionThreshold="1"
                android:id="@+id/actv_arrival"
                android:hint="Arrival"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_date"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:singleLine="true"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/et_date"
                android:hint="Date"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_searching"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is MainActivity:

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    private EditText et_date;
    private TextInputLayout tilDate;

    // private Button btn_searching;
    private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;



    public  SearchFragment(){

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        et_date = (EditText)getView().findViewById(R.id.et_date);
        et_date.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        //et_date.requestFocus();
        tilDate= (TextInputLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.input_layout_arrival);
        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
        setDateTimeField();

    }

    private void setDateTimeField() {
        try {
           et_date.setOnClickListener(this);
            tilDate.setOnClickListener(this);
            final Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth - 1);
                    if (newDate.getTime().getTime() > (newCalendar.getTime().getTime())) {

                      final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Notification").setMessage("This is a date of future! We will get current date for this review!").show();

                        //this code below is coppied in https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/auto-close-dialog-after-a-specific-time/
                        final Timer t = new Timer();
                        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                            public void run() {
                                builder.dismiss(); // when the task active then close the dialog
                                t.cancel(); // also just top the timer thread, otherwise, you may receive a crash report
                            }
                        }, 2000); // after 2 second (or 2000 miliseconds), the task will be active.
                        et_date.setText(dateFormatter.format(newCalendar.getTime()));

                    } else {
                        newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                        et_date.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
                    }
                }
            }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            messages("Something Wrong!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fargment_search, container, false);


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public void messages(String msg) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Notification").setMessage(msg).setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==et_date){
            fromDatePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: try android:focusable="false" on your edittext

Comment: @bhargav thanks you so much, it works perfectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding

```
android:focusable="false"
```

It should work.

Your keyboard pops up when widget gains focus. So to prevent this behaviour set focusable to false.

Answer taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12560605/4211264