# EditText OnClickListener taking two clicks to work

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have 4 `EditTexts` in my activity. Each one has an `OnClickListener` that when called will check a checkbox for me. However, when I first press on the `EditText`, the `EditText` turns blue, but the checkbox does not check. It is only when I press on it again that the `OnClickListener` takes effect and checks the box.

Does anyone know why this is?

Example code:

```
public View.OnClickListener respiratoryOnClickListenerv(final View v) {
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CheckBox respiratoryCheckbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.vitals_2);
            respiratoryCheckbox.setChecked(true);
            respiratoryCheckbox.callOnClick();
        }
    };
    return listener;
}


respiratoryEditText.setOnClickListener(respiratoryOnClickListenerv(rootView));
```

Comment: you should use focuschange {foucus = true} instead of click{}

Comment: Can you elaborate? I'm a little confused

Comment: Have a look at the `OnFocusChangeListener()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnFocusChangeListener(android.view.View.OnFocusChangeListener), the first tap on the EditText is focusing the view.

Comment: respiratoryEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){  onFoucsChange(View v, boolean focus){ if(focus){//do you logic}}}).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When a user interacts with a UI element the various listeners are called in a top down order. (For example: OnTouch -> OnFocusChange -> OnClick.) If a listener has been defined (with setOn...Listener) and it consumes this event: the lower priority listeners will not be called. By its nature the first time you touch an EditText it receives focus with OnFocusChangeListener so that the user can type. The action is consumed here therefor OnClick is not called. Each successive touch doesn't change the focus so the event trickles down to the OnClickListener.

From that, you have three choices:

1) Set the focusable attribute to false in your XML:

android:focusable="false"

Now the OnClickListener will fire every time it is clicked. But this makes the EditText useless since the user can no longer enter text.

2) Implement an OnFocusChangeListener along with the OnClickListener:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus) {
             //Do your work
        }

    }
});
```

Together you can catch every touch event on your EditText.

3) Implement an OnTouchListener by itself:

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction())
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onTouch: Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

    });
```

This will execute every time the EditText is touched. Notice that this event returns a boolean. Returning false means that the event will continue trickle down and reach the built in onFocusChangeListener allowing it to receive text.

Hope this help!

Comment: if(hasFocus) {//Do your work} will work only once, until the focus changes to !hasFocus.

Comment: @Brejuro so check my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39841661/4576879