# How to hide soft Keyboard without focus in Android?

Tags: android, keyboard

I meet this case, I check the soft keyboard is on and I want to dismiss in the code, when I use the below code it cannot dismiss the keyboard, because the code can not find any focus, but the keyboard is still on, so how can I hide it?

```
private void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    Activity activity = (Activity) sContext;
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {

        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        //((Activity) sContext).getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    } else {

            Log.i(sClassTag,"focus not found");

    }
}
```

Comment: `View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}`

Comment: `InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: Great! It works for me, thank you ! maybe you can move this to an answer, and I can vote.

Comment: Okay..glad to help  :))

Comment: Use this for Hide keybord
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67088797/14653921)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use this

You can force Android to hide the virtual keyboard using the `InputMethodManager`, calling `hideSoftInputFromWindow`, passing in the token of the window containing your focused view.

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

This will force the keyboard to be hidden in all situations. In some cases you will want to pass in `InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY` as the second parameter to ensure you only hide the keyboard when the user didn't explicitly force it to appear (by holding down menu).

or this

```
InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

you can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)  activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: Always consider to provide comment for your solution. What does your code do in order to solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use these extension to toggle the keyboard:

```
fun Context.showKeyboard() {
    val imm = this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0)
}

fun Context.hideKeyboard() {
    val imm = this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY)
}

fun Context.toggleKeyboard() {
    val imm = this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    if (imm.isActive) {
        hideKeyboard()
    } else {
        showKeyboard()
    }
}
```