# How to get a callback when item inside RecyclerView is hidden/visible?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayoutManager` with video streams in each grid cell. I need some kind of callback for visibility on each cell to know when to stop the video in the cells that are not visible on screen and start the videos on the cells that are visible.

I've experimented with `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` to then use `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` and `findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` to get the range of visible items. But I haven't found a way to find the items that have moved out of screen.

Is there a way to obtain all the hidden and visible items from the `RecyclerView` or `RecyclerView.Adapter` or `GridLayoutManager`? Or is there a way for the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` to listen for changes in its hidden/visible state to stop the video?

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989218/get-visible-items-in-recyclerview

Comment: Not that much as I've explained in my post

Comment: The core part of your question may be a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678632/is-there-a-callback-for-when-recyclerview-has-finished-showing-its-items-after-i