# Kotlin callback when RecyclerView.Adapter has drawn all elements

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using a recyclerview to list some elements and I want to know when the RecyclerView.Adapter has drawn all the elements I sent. there is any way to do that?

Comment: RecyclerView only draw the elements/items you see on screen at a time. It'll not draw all element in one shot.

Comment: RecyclerView won't draw all the items at once? Are you trying to know if all the items are drawn or only the visible items are drawn?

Comment: I mean, i need a callback when all elements of that adapter has been drawn

Comment: All of them?  Including the ones that aren't onscreen?

Comment: Yes, i am using a skeleton library and I want to catch when that adapter finish to hide that effect

Comment: Question is a bit old, but I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32679359/13950996)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this :

```cs
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter`<`MyAdapter.MyViewHolder`>`(){

    // And then please Implement methods here of it.
}
```

Comment: I mean, i need a callback when all elements of that adapter has been drawn