# Recycleview add listener when using scrollToPosition() method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use `recycleView` and to scroll to a particular `view` position and show a `popupWindow` below that `view`, if layout is not scrolled then `popupWindow` will not be shown at correct position since layout is not loaded. Recycleview's `onScrollClickListener()` doesn't get triggered when using `recyclerView.scrollToTopPosition(pos)` method. I have searched similar issue on stackoverflow and `LayoutChangeListener()` is suggested, but that also fails to work in my case.

Is there any other suggstion how to get `onScroll` callback when scrolling is done? I have been searching for a solution for the some hours now no luck.

My code

```
GenericFragmentButton fragmentButton = fragmentButtonsList.get(position).getFragmentButton();
int adapterPosition = groupAdapter.getAdapterPosition(fragmentButton);


layoutChangeListener = new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        showShowCase(position, fragmentButtonsList, fragmentButton);
    }
};

recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(layoutChangeListener);

recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapterPosition);
```

[image]
Showcase is supposed to show below the highlighted icon, but for some reasons when i use `addOnLayoutChangeListener()` it is shown at bottom, most of layout is hidden. I get this issue when i use `addOnLayoutChangeListener()` only so that's the reason i am searching for an alternate way to detect on scroll complete.

**Update:** Displaying `popupWindow` after a delay works but I don't think it's good solution.

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.postDelayed(() -> showShowCase(position, fragmentButtonsList, fragmentButton), 200);
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [RecyclerView.OnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener)?

Comment: yes, onScrollClickListener's onStateChanged() doesn't get triggered if we use scrollToPosition().

Comment: Right...then consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32679359/6287910) as an alternative. It may be better behaved than the layout change listener.